# If $|f''| \leq M|f |$, how to prove that $f(x) \equiv 0$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

This time I come across a problem.
A function  $f(x)$ is defined on an  interval $[a,b]$ , and given that $f(a) = f'(a) = 0$ , there exists a also const $M$ which satisfies $$|f''(x)| \le M|f(x)|$$
How to obtain $f(x) \equiv 0$ ?

**Edit**: the content of the related section is about the differential form of Grönwall's inequality [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality):

> If $f(x)$ is differential on $[a,b]$, $f(a)=0$ and there exists a const $M$ which satisfies $$|f'(x)| \le M|f(x)|$$ we can easily obtain  $$f(x) \equiv 0$$.

I tried to use a similar method in the book to prove the second order derivative situation, but without success.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=primitive+%28f%28x%29%29%27%27%2Ff%28x%29%3Dc I think it helps !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach using the fundamental theorem. If $x_0 \in (a,b)$ and $x \in [a,x_0]$ the hypothesis $f(a) = f'(a)$ gives you
$$f(x) = \int_a^x f'(t) \, dt = \int_a^x \int_a^t f''(y) \, dy dt $$ so that $$|f(x)| \le \int_a^x \int_a^t |f''(y)| \, dy dt \le \max_{[a,x_0]} |f''| \int_a^x \int_a^t \, dydt \le M \left( \max_{[a,x_0]}|f| \right) \frac{(x_0-a)^2}{2}.$$
Now take the maximum of all $x \in [a,x_0]$ on the left-hand side to get
$$\max_{[a,x_0]}|f| \le M \left( \max_{[a,x_0]}|f| \right) \frac{(x_0-a)^2}{2}.$$
Choose $x_0$ sufficiently close to $a$ so that
$$\frac{(x_0 - a)^2}{2} < \frac 1M$$
to find that
$$\max_{[a,x_0]} |f| = 0.$$
Thus $f$ is identically zero on a nondegenerate interval $[a,x_0]$ *whose length depends only on $a$ and $M$*.

Can you proceed from here to show the function is identically zero on $[a,b]$?

Comment: I don't know how to proceed from here...

Comment: Well, the same reasoning says that $f$ is identically zero on a nondegenerate interval $[x_0,x_1]$ *whose length depends only on $a$ and $M$*...

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Umberto P.